# R - Problem Storing lubridate dates in a dataframe

Tags: r, date, lubridate

When I'm trying to store date in a DF it is getting represented as a number instead of a data format.  Here is my example.

```
library(lubridate)

df1 = data.frame(task = c('do somthing', 'do something else', 'do something more')
                 ,Start_date = c(NA, NA, NA))

Start_date = ymd("2023-12-01")
df1$Date_Start[1] = Start_date

Start_date     #this returns a "2023-12-01"
df1$Date_Start[1]  #this returns a 19692
```

I want df1$Date_Start[1] to store "2023-12-01"

Comment: `df1 %>% mutate(Start_date = ymd("2023-12-01"))`?

Comment: `df1$Date_Start = as.character(Start_date)`? or `format(Start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `lubridate`, since you will get the same result here with `as.Date` as you do with `lubridate::ymd`.

When you create a column of NA values but you plan to write dates into it, you need to tell R that you intend to use it for dates by using `as.Date(NA)` to fill the column. Otherwise, R will convert the date to a numeric value.

```r
library(lubridate)

df1 = data.frame(task = c('do somthing', 'do something else', 'do something more')
                 ,Date_Start = c(NA, NA, NA))

Start_date = ymd("2023-12-01")
df1$Date_Start <- as.Date(NA)
df1$Date_Start[1] <- Start_date[1]

Start_date 
#> [1] "2023-12-01"
df1$Date_Start[1] 
#> [1] "2023-12-01"

df1
#>                task Date_Start
#> 1       do somthing 2023-12-01
#> 2 do something else       <NA>
#> 3 do something more       <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

`Start_date` variable was created as a logical object:

```
str(df1)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ task      : chr  "do somthing" "do something else" "do something more"
 $ Start_date: logi  NA NA NA
```

After you defining a date at the first element, the object was converted into numeric

```
str(df1)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ task      : chr  "do somthing" "do something else" "do something more"
 $ Start_date: num  19692 NA NA
```

You can create your data.frame by defining the type of `Start_date` variable as a Date object.

```
df1 = data.frame(task = c('do somthing', 'do something else', 'do something more'), Start_date = as.Date(NA))

str(df1)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ task      : chr  "do somthing" "do something else" "do something more"
 $ Start_date: Date, format: NA NA NA
```

Now you can define your date at the first element:

```
df1$Start_date[1] = Start_date
df1
               task Start_date
1       do somthing 2023-12-01
2 do something else       <NA>
3 do something more       <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify directly your Date format:

```
library(lubridate)

df1 = data.frame(task = c('do somthing', 'do something else', 'do something more')
             ,Start_date = c(NA, NA, NA))

df1$Start_date[1] <- format(ymd("2023-12-01"), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: This stores the date as a character string rather than a date though. You would get the same result with `df1$Start_date[1] <- "2023-12-01"`

Comment: After you re-foramt a `Date` object, it becomes a pure character string and lose all the attributes a `Date` has. See `class(ymd("2023-12-01"))` and `class(format(ymd("2023-12-01")))`.